# Print specific element of array in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I am new to smarty and I want to print a specific element of array in smarty.
I am using vtiger open source and vtiger uses smarty.

I am writing this to print a specific element of array. I am doing this in a foreach loop:

```
{foreach from=$LISTVIEW_ENTRIES key=j item=LISTVIEW_ENTRY name=listview}
{$LISTVIEW_ENTRIES[2]}

{/foreach}
```

I am printing all array with a function of `{$LISTVIEW_ENTRIES|@debug_print_var}`

It gave this:

```
Array (13)
57 => Accounts_Record_Model Object (1)
   ->rawData = Array (20)
    0 => "Nadine Campbell"
    accountname => "Nadine Campbell"
    1 => "Accidental Discharge of Water"
    cf_763 => "Accidental Discharge of Water"
    2 => "2014-09-07"
    cf_765 => "2014-09-07"
    3 => "Refer to Attorney"
    cf_757 => "Refer to Attorney"
    4 => "Progressive Insurance"
    cf_737 => "Progressive Insurance"
    5 => "2015-02-26 12:52:35"
    modifiedtime => "2015-02-26 12:52:35"
    6 => "42 SW 14 Avenue"
    bill_street => "42 SW 14 Avenue"
    7 => "Delray Beach"
    bill_city => "Delray Beach"
    8 => "Patty Mitrov"
    cf_809 => "Patty Mitrov"
    9 => "57"
    accountid => "57"
```

Now can you please tell me how to print specific element from that array?
I want to print index # 2 from that array

Comment: PLEASE UP-VOTE THE ANSWER ALSO. THANKS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

My array format is like this:-

```
    Array (84)
    id_product => "112"
    id_supplier => "6"
    id_manufacturer => "0"
    id_category_default => "2"
    id_shop_default => "1"
    id_tax_rules_group => "7"
    on_sale => "0"
    online_only => "0"
    ean13 => ""
    upc => ""
    ecotax => "0.000000"
    quantity => 0

  {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
        {$product['id_product']}
  {/foreach}
```

Output is:- 112